# Python Boolean error?

Tags: python

Ok so I'm creating a loop:

```
def equ(par1,par2):
    con1=4/par1

    ready=False
    add=False

    if ready==True:
        if add==True:
            par2+=con1
            add=False
            print("true")
        elif add==False:
            par2-=con1
            add=True
            print("False")
    elif ready==False:
        par2=con1
    ready=True
    input()
    return par2
```

Every time I run the program it doesn't do what it's supposed to. I notice that it will NOT change ready to true. Could any one give me some help? THANKS! :)

Comment: You do not have a loop here. You are just giving an `if` conditional. what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Urgh. `ready = True`???

Comment: You should consider using `if ready:` instead of `if ready==True:` and `if not ready:` instead of `if ready==False:`

Comment: Never mind guys I figured it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have no looping construct.  You only have a linear flow of logic.

Second, `ready==True` will never be true, since it is explicitly set to `False` before that code block is ever hit.

If you're intending to reuse the boolean value `ready`, then you'd either want to preserve its state somewhere outside of the scope of the method - once you leave the method, it goes right back through and sets it to `False` again.

Comment: I have a loop outside it! :/ But thank you. You DID help me. I'm just going to change it up a little then check. Once I'm done with that could you help me out with the second error? I'll tell you in a minute.

Comment: That may take it outside of the scope of the question, and I've got a few things to do...I don't mind helping, but you may be better off creating a new question to solve your other problems.

Comment: Well it has to do with the same thing...But OK! I'll make a new question! Thanks for the help! :)